# getDC of dialog child element

Tags: c++, mfc, paint

I have an MFC dialog with a button and a Picture control. When I click the button, I draw line inside the picture control.

The problem is that the CDC I get is the whole dialog client area. So the line is drawn outside the picture control. I need to get the CDC of only the Picture control, because the line coordinates should be relative to picture control rectangle.

Here is the code:

```
void SimulatorDlg::OnBnClicked()
{   
    CDC *pDC = GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEO_PREVIEW)->GetDC();
    pDC->MoveTo(0,0);
    pDC->LineTo(100,100);
    ReleaseDC(pDC);
}
```

IDC_VIDEO_PREVIEW is the id of the Picture Control, which is inside the dialog.

Comment: Is your problem the fact that the drawing is not clipped?

Comment: No, my problem is that I need to know the exact coordinates of my picture control, so that I can calculate where to draw my lines. I have lines coordinates, but I need to recalculate tme, so that they will suit the size of the picture control.

Comment: Have you tried using CWnd::GetClientRect() or CWnd::GetWindowRect()?